# Alignment of mulitple labels - HTML, CSS

Tags: html, css, alignment, label

I am having a problem aligning my labels.

What i have right now:

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="personalinformation">
<label for="" class="info">Firstname:</label>
<label for="">Bill</label>
</div>

<div class="personalinformation">
<label for="" class="info">Lastname:</label>
<label for="">Gates</label>
</div>

<div class="personalinformation">
<label for="" class="info">Country:</label>
<label for="">France</label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.personalinformation {
text-align: center;
margin-left: auto;
text-justify: inter-word;
margin: 0 auto 1em auto;
}

.info {
font-weight: bold;
text-align: left;
margin-right: 50px;
}
```

How do i get my labels to align like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to set a fixed width and the float left property for each label. 
Look at the snippet:
http://www.bootply.com/wEqBL8Tvo0

Regards

Comment: What if I want to have all the labels like you have them, but at the center of the page?

Comment: set a container div which englobes everything, set a specifically width and use auto property for the margin. Look: http://www.bootply.com/q9x6cX9dFj

Comment: But then you have that extra space, in the container div on the right so only the div is centered but the text is not.

Answer (score 1):

Labels are intended to be for form inputs. You're really doing more of a definition list here. Try:

```
<dl class="personalinformation">
  <dt class="info">Firstname:</dt>
  <dd>Bill</dd>
</dl>
<dl class="information">
  <dt class="info">Lastname:</dt>
  <dd>Gates</dd>
  <dt class="info">Country:</dt>
  <dd>France</dd>
</dl>
```

with something like

```
dt,dd{display:inline-block; width:40%}
dl{margin: 0}
dt{text-align:left}
dd{text-align:right}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without changing your HTML, you can give a fixed width to your `info` class CSS:

```
.info {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100px; //change this to what you want
    display: inline-block;
}
```

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/darienh/c2dbbfmq/).

Comment: What if I want to have all the labels like you have them, but at the center of the page?

Comment: I would probably change your HTML to `table` element and put a `margin: 0 auto` on the `table`. See [updated fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/darienh/c2dbbfmq/1/).